# Use Postional bind variable to query Sub String in oracle database

Tags: python, database, oracle

I am not able to use positional binding in my code.

My code:

```
value ="Some value"

cur.execute("Select * from TABLENAME where FIELD like '%:1%' ",{'1':value})
```

Error:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using trying to use dynamic SQL query, then you should do it like this:

```
query := 'select * From my_table where cola = :i';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query USING 'value';
```

Here ':i' is the bind variable. This will get replaced by the value you pass in the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE command in the USING section.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Python so this is untested, but Oracle parses your `:1` as a text literal because it's in quotes. I think you'll need to construct the wildcard before passing it to the cursor, so something like this:

```
value ="%Some value%"

cur.execute("select * from TABLENAME where COLUMNNAME like :1", {'1':value})
```